# C#, SQL: one function to service INSERT INTO for different tables

Tags: c#, sql, function, insert

First and foremost: I used to develop software 20 years ago - decided to get my hands "dirty" again. So... please, pretty please, don't use too technical language. :)

I'm doing some database to store a high amount of chats, multiple tables.
I'm somewhat comfortable with C# but my knowledge of SQL coding is mostly copy-paste from the web and then adapt.
My goal is to build a C# function that I can use when inserting data into any of my tables. Doing this by:
function (string table, string[] fields, object[] values)

So... this is what I came up with. I'll be testing and adapting all through the way.
But would be nice to have some opinion. If I'm totally on the wrong path, then I better just give up before smashing my head onto an error for the 100th time.

```
    public static int InsertIntoTable(string table, List<string> fields, List<object> values)
    {
        if (fields.Count != values.Count)
            return -99;

        string query = "INSERT INTO " + table;

        query += " (";
        foreach (string field in fields)
            query += "[" + field + "],";
        query = query.Remove(query.Length - 1, 1); query += ")";

        query += " VALUES (";
        foreach (string field in fields)
            query += "@" + field + ",";
        query = query.Remove(query.Length - 1, 1); query += ")";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(fields[i], values[i]));

        if(command.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
            new Exception("SQL INSERT command inserted not 1 row");

        int key = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();

        return key;
    }
```

Comment: Have to advise very strongly against this. Building queries like this was deemed a bad idea a long time ago. We now parameterize our queries (or [fall victim to SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/)). This method trusts its inputs *way* too much. To mitigate that, it's going to quickly become a "god function" of sorts. What you're trying to do is better done with an ORM. All that work has been done for you and been put through extensive testing.

Comment: I do understand that it is open to push whatever into it.
I'd seen the cartoon before and it came to mind.

Will take a look onto that ORM thing... I should stick to political studies an outsource this thing. :)

Thanks.